# InputBox Position

Tags: c#, winforms, position, inputbox

How to open the Interaction.InputBox to center of the form? I know there is a code for the position of the InputBox

```
Interaction.InputBox("Question?", "Title", "Default Text", x,y);
```

I will be using this InputBox in different form of different sizes. Is there a way to open the InputBox in the center of the form? Or I have to position them individually on each form?

[image]

Is it possible also to reposition the OKbutton and Cancelbutton of InputBox?

Comment: Create your own form and place `TextBox`, `Label` and `Buttons` as you want. Then you can always call it in every form as `inputForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;` and then `inputForm.ShowDialog(this);`

Answer (score 3):

Here is something simple to calculate the center of a form, the extra offset is for the size of the input box.

```
{
    int x = this.Left + (this.Width / 2) - 200;
    int y = this.Top + (this.Height / 2) - 100;
}
```

Pass these into the input box for x and y

Answer (score 2):

If you want full customisation then creating your own form is the best way to go as indicated in Fabio's comment.

However, if you just want to approximately centre the box and you will be doing it many times then you could write your own extension method to show and position the input box for you:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static string CentredInputBox(this Form form, string prompt, string title = "", string defaultResponse = "")
    {
        const int approxInputBoxWidth = 370;
        const int approxInputBoxHeight = 158;

        int left = form.Left + (form.Width / 2) - (approxInputBoxWidth / 2);
        left = left < 0 ? 0 : left;
        int top = form.Top + (form.Height / 2) - (approxInputBoxHeight / 2);
        top = top < 0 ? 0 : top;

        return Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(prompt, title, defaultResponse, left, top);
    }
}
```

Usage from within a form:

```
this.CentredInputBox("MyPrompt", "MyTitle", "MyDefaultResponse");
```

It's not perfect because if the box is bigger than normal for some reason then it won't quite be in the centre, and I think its size is variable depending on how much text is in it. However, it shouldn't be far off in normal usage.

Answer (score 2):

To center your `InputBox`, you can try using `Win32` functions to deal with it. This code works for you:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr afterHwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int flag);
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string caption);        
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT rect);
//RECT structure
public struct RECT {
   public int left, top, right, bottom;
}
public void ShowCenteredInputBox(string prompt, string title, string defaultReponse){
   BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {           
       while (true) {               
           IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(null, title + "\n\n\n");//this is just a trick to identify your InputBox from other window with the same caption
           if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
               RECT rect;
               GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);
               int w = rect.right - rect.left;
               int h = rect.bottom - rect.top;
               int x = Left + (Width - w) / 2;
               int y = Top + (Height - h) / 2;
               SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, x, y, w, h, 0x40);//SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40
               break;
           }
       };
   }));
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(prompt, title + "\n\n\n", defaultResponse,0,0);
}
```

Of course you can also change the position of the buttons, label and TextBox on your `InputBox` but **it's very nasty and tricky, we can say that it's not simple**. The recommended solution for you is to **create new standard form in `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, add controls to it and use the method `ShowDialog()` to show your form.**. Of course it requires more code to do but it allows you to fully customize the look and feel and its behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the InputBox's starting position. There's a property for that

```
InputBox ib = new InputBox();

ib.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

Where as FormStartPosition is an enum, from which you can select your desired position!

Answer (score -1):

You can sipmly use -1 for x and y:
Interaction.InputBox("Question?", "Title", "Default Text", -1,-1);